# Office Js , What is the different of `/hosted/office.debug.js` and `hosted/office.js`

Tags: office-js

I have an add-in application for outlook, I look at the codebase (html file), there are 2 scripts,

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
```

My question:

1. What is the difference between the two scripts?
2. If I am using `office.debug.js` version, what features can I use for debugging?

Comment: `office.js` is at least [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) and is otherwise unreadable while debugging. `office.debug.js` is not minified and thus readable, useful for debugging.  If you plug those URL's into your browser you'd see the difference immediately.

Comment: is there any special method that we can i use for debugging or it just like only done on the console?

Comment: That's a very broad question. It really depends on the tools you're using.  I'd start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office). Good luck.